# Is there any reason to use NSInteger instead of uint8_t with NS_ENUM?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

The general standard appears to use `NS_ENUM` with `NSInteger` as the base type. Why is this the case? Assuming less than 256 cases (which covers almost any enumeration), is there any reason to use that instead of `uint8_t`, which could use less memory space? Either imports into Swift fine.

This is different than `NS_OPTIONS`, where a larger type makes sense, since you shouldn't be doing any bit math with enumerations, and you can use every number representable by the base type as a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title:

> Is there any reason to use NSInteger instead of uint8_t with NS_ENUM?

is probably not.

When declaring an enum in C if no underlying type is specified the compiler is free to choose any suitable type from `char` and the signed and unsigned integer types which can *at least* represent all the values required. The current Xcode/Clang compiler picks a 4-byte integer. One could reasonably assume the compiler writers made an informed choice - some balance of performance and storage.

Smaller types, such as `uint8_t`, will usually be aligned on smaller boundaries in memory (or on disc) - but that is only of benefit if the adjacent field matches the alignment e.g. if a 2-byte size typed field follows a 1-byte sized typed field then unless otherwise specified (e.g. with a `#pragma packed`) there will probably be an intervening unused byte.

Whether any performance or storage differences are significant will be heavily dependent on the application. Follow the usual rule of thumb - don't optimise until an issue is found.

However if you find *semantic* benefit in limiting the size then certainly do so - there is no general reason you shouldn't. The choice is similar to picking signed vs. unsigned integers, some programmers avoid unsigned types for values that will be ≥ 0 unless absolutely required for the extra range, while others appreciate the semantic benefit.

Summary: There is no right answer, its largely a subjective issue.

HTH

Comment: Only a little remark: *from char and the signed and unsigned integer types* `char` is an integer type.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - True, and it is important to remember this. However it is not a *signed integer type* or *unsigned integer type*. The list for `enum` above is what is given in the C Standard: "Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type." The Standard does not use integer type itself here as that term is defined as: "The type `char`, the signed and unsigned integer types, and the enumerated types are collectively called *integer types*"; and the underlying type of an enumeration cannot be another enum. Aren't Standards fun :-)

Comment: To make it funnier `signed char` is a standard signed integer type: *There are five standard signed integer types, designated as signed char, short int, int, long int, and long long int.* The whole story behind that is that the default signedness od `char` is implementation-defined. (As you surely know, just for the protocol.) Yeah, standards are fun. I like that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all: The memory footprint is close to completely meaningless. You are talking about 1 Byte vs. 4/8 Bytes. (If the memory alignment does not force the usage of 4/8 bytes whatever you chosed.) How many `NS_ENUM` (C) objects do you want to have in your running app?

I guess that the reason is pretty easy: `NSInteger` is akin of "catch all" integer type in Cocoa. That makes assignments easier, especially you do not have to care about assigning a bigger integer type to a smaller one. Without casting this would lead to warnings.

Having more than one integer type in a desktop app with a 32/64 bit model is akin of an anachronism. Nor a Mac neither a MacBook neither an iPhone is an embedded micro controller …

Answer (score 0):

You can use any integer data type including uint8_t with NS_ENUM as.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(uint8_t, eEnumAddEditViewMode) {
  eWBEnumAddMode,
  eWBEnumEditMode
```

};

In old c style standard NSInteger is default, because NSInteger is akin of "catch all" integer type in objective c. and developer can easily type boxing and unboxing with their own variable. This is just developer friendly best practise.